# When i run heroku ps:scale web=1 command i am getting this error. Can anyone help me with this

Tags: python, django, heroku

When i run heroku `ps:scale web=1` command i am getting this error.

```
▸    Missing required flag:
▸    -a, --app APP  app to run command against
▸    See more help with --help
```

Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: You are missing the required flag `--app` to run the command against.

Comment: @evilSnobu but i am not able to figure out why the app name is required. Even the heroku docs say that no app name is required.

Comment: @evilSnobu what the final command to scale dynamos would be.

Comment: Are you in your project directory when you run this command?

Comment: Perhaps you have more than one heroku app in your heroku account? If so, just provide the name of the app you want to scale as follows: "ps:scale web=1 --app <name_of_app>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to mention the app name against which you intend to run the command from CLI despite having a single app.

When running commands from CLI, it is advised to always mention the app name using

```
--app 'app-name'
```

against every command.

If you want to avoid doing that, you can set your heroku git remote app repo to a specific app, using the command

```
heroku git:remote -a 'app_name'
```

That should help you not having to type the app_name every time.

About scaling the dynos, you can read [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scaling#scaling-from-the-cli).